# Parsing simple JSON to android

Tags: android, json, parsing

### Having problem parsing JSON data into android

- I have descriptively mentioned the problem i am facing, Any ideas on
  how to overcome this

Initially I have used the JSON from url

**`URL:: http://54.218.73.244:8084/`**

**JSONParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONArray jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java**

```
    public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends Activity {

        // url to make request
        private static String url = "http://54.218.73.244:8084/";
        private HashMap<Integer, String> contentsMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.on

Create(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    int id = c.getInt("id");
                    String name = c.getString("content");

                    contentsMap.put(id, name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(contentsMap.get(1));

        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText(contentsMap.get(2));


    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="10sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="TextView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="TextView2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**OUTPUT::**

*The output for above code obtained is*

[image: FIG-1]

---

Next i change my URL to

**`URL:: http://54.218.73.244:7003/`**

And without changing other part of the code

Now i get the error screen as

[image: FIG-2]

---

**ERROR LOG**

```
08-10 09:45:41.731: E/JSON Parser(448): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Cannot of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
08-10 09:45:41.737: D/AndroidRuntime(448): Shutting down VM
08-10 09:45:41.737: W/dalvikvm(448): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-10 09:45:41.772: E/AndroidRuntime(448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 09:45:41.772: E/AndroidRuntime(448): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.json_web/com.example.json_web.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 09:45:41.772: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-10 09:45:41.772: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-10 09:45:41.772: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-10 09:45:41.772: E/AndroidRuntime(448):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
```

**My analysis according to error ::**

- there is error parsing String cannot be converted to JSONArray
- How to solve this error ?

---

- for URL :: `http://54.218.73.244:8084/`

JSON reply i get is ::   `[{"id":1,"content":"Hello"},{"id":2,"content":"World"}]`

- for URL :: `http://54.218.73.244:7003/`

JSON reply i get is :: `[{"id":1,"content":"Hello"},{"id":2,"content":"World"}]`

*Structure of the JSON is same, Please confirm this by using the url in the browser*

---

**Thanks,**

---

Comment: how abt the parameter and all did u change the code ?? is the structure of json same for both urls?

Comment: Apart from the url in the code , i have not changed anything in the code

Comment: can you post your json arry??

Comment: okay, but the reponse must be differnt right ? can u post the json response from both urls?

Comment: Better post the String you obtain from the 2 URLs

Comment: are you getting proper data in output?

Comment: @ Stacks28 & @ Shani Goriwal @reTs............... I have updated my code ...... please have a look at it.

Comment: @ Shani Goriwal ....... I am getting proper JSON response from server .... it is the parsing i need to change .... i dont knw which line of the code

Comment: when i'm accessing your two URL's i'm getting exception.

Comment: @ Harish ..... In server ... i have used noejs to generate json for first url `but` i have used express to generate JSON from second url ..... im successful for generating json from both url

Comment: A `LOG.d("", "response from server: " + json)` before `jObj = new JSONArray(json);` would help a lot in diagnostic.

Wild guess: the server 7073 cannot be reached from the app and `json` is `Cannot ...`

Comment: @ RC  .... Solution was to replace POST request with GET request in case of second url for parser .... as im using Express in server side ..... problem got solved ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server at `http://54.218.73.244:7003/` does not support a `POST` request.

So either make your server accept `POST` requests or change the following line in `JSONParser` class.

```
//HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); //Remove this and replace with the below

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
```

Comment: It supports both GET and POST. This will not solve the problem

Comment: Try posting the above url, you will not get a `JSON` response

Comment: @ShamimAhmmed no worries, it happens :)

Comment: @ Sunil Mishra ........ Your solution worked like a charm ...... I replaced `Post` with `Get` request as u suggested ! ..... Now i am able to  parse JSON from second URL.... I dont know Express must support both Get and post requests .... must be another way to use post request .... anyways my problem got solved , Thanks !

Comment: @Sky Welcome! Ya you may need to debug why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

//MainActivity.java

package com.example.jsonparsing;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    CutsomAdapter adapter;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        new getData()
                .execute();
    }

    private class getData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

            Dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
            Dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                try {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("Your Url");

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();           

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line+"n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

                // try parse the string to a JSON object
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    JSONObject jObj1 = new JSONObject(jObj.getJSONObject("response").toString());
                    jsonarray = jObj1.getJSONArray("venues");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject c = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                       // JSONObject c1 = jsonarray1.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        map.put("name", c.getString("name"));
                        Log.e("Name", c.getString("name"));
                        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject jObj3 = new JSONObject(c.getString("location"));
                        if(jObj3.has("formattedAddress"))
                       map.put("address", jObj3.getString("formattedAddress"));

                        arraylist.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }
                    return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            Log.e("Responce", arraylist.toString());
            adapter=new CutsomAdapter(MainActivity.this,arraylist);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            Dialog.dismiss();

        }
    }

}
```

//customadapter.java

```
package com.example.jsonparsing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CutsomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values;
    private Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CutsomAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.values = arraylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView textname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView textaddress = (TextView) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.address);

        textname.setText(values.get(position).get("name"));
        textaddress.setText(values.get(position).get("address"));

        return itemView;
    }

}
```

//activitymain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

//row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="addess"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code fixes and how?  Code only answers without any explanation are considered low quality and sometimes end up being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Cannot of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

from the error log as far as I can see the problem is the JSON string you're trying to parse is invalid.

The problem actually have NOTHING to do with the code.Just Make sure you get proper JSON response from server.